# Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\.. on line 19

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un servicio de inventario pero tengo un error que no he podido solucionar,
necesito que me reste de la base de datos donde esta el campo cantidad_productos, esto tiene que restar lo que estan enviando por un input[image: Tabla Inventario]:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php-login\controllers\controller_salida_productos.php
>   on line 19

Que podrá ser.
Gracias

```
<?php

    include ("../conexion.php");

     //confirmar que todos los datos se envian correcto y no estan vacios
     if(isset($_POST ['cantidad']) && !empty($_POST['cantidad']))
     {
         $query = "INSERT INTO devolucion VALUES('null','$_POST[cantidad]','$_POST[producto]','$_POST[fecha]','$_POST[descripcion]')";
         $conn->query($query);
         echo $query;
         echo("Los productos fueron Agregados Exitosamente <br>");
         echo "<br><a href='../salida_productos.php'>Añadir otro Producto</a>";
     } else {
         echo"verfique los datos insertados";
     }

     $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
     $operacion = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cantidad_productos FROM Inventario_Producto WHERE  Entrada_Productos_Producto_idProductos='$_POST[producto]'");
     $resta=( (int)$operacion)-((int)$cantidad);
     $envio="UPDATE Inventario_Producto Set cantidad_productos=$resta";
 ?>
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido potencialmente contiene vulnerabilidades de seguridad graves y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público. Estás usando MySQLi, deberías utilizar sentencias preparadas y no concatenar cadenas para formar las sentencias SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tienes aqui:

```
$operacion = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cantidad_productos FROM Inventario_Producto WHERE  Entrada_Productos_Producto_idProductos='$_POST[producto]'");

resta=( (int)$operacion)-((int)$cantidad);
```

Tienes que almacenar las filas de esa consulta en una variable para después restarla a `$cantidad`

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT cantidad_productos FROM Inventario_Producto WHERE  Entrada_Productos_Producto_idProductos='$_POST[producto]'");

$operacion = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

resta = $operacion['cantidad_productos'] - $cantidad;
```

Comment: puedes mejorar la pregunta para evitar el SQL inyection

Comment: me funciono perfecto a la hora de realizar la operación, el problema es que no esta alterando la base de datos, pegue la misma operación que me da el sistema y la ejecute directamente el mysql y si funciona bien

Comment: @JuanCamiloRairanRodriguez no uses las respuestas para dar más información: edita tu pregunta o comenta en las respuestas (puedes comentar en tus publicaciones sin problemas)

Comment: @JuanCamiloRairanRodriguez has ejecutado la ultima consulta? algo como `mysqli_query($conn,$envio);`  ?

Comment: @JackNavaRow por supuesto, un ejemplo con consultas preparadas para evitar la inyección SQL seria lo recomendable. Pero estoy en el curro y no puedo jeje, pero gracias por la sugerencia, en cuanto pueda edito mi respuesta.

Comment: sii me faltaba ejecutar la ultima consulta, excelente me funciono bien
y me pondré a trabajar en el tema de evitar inyección sql
Gracias